# Help with regular expression

Tags: preg-match

I have the following lines I have to match

```
A
Ab
A#
F#7+9d
G3+9d
Gm
```

Basically I need to match the first letter and the **#** or the **b** following. I also need to match anything else (such as the **7+9d** or the **m**).

Here is my code so far but it's not picking up the second part

preg_match('/A-G([A-Z0-9+]?)/i', $start_key, $matches)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
/^A-G(#|b)?([A-Z0-9+]*)$/i
```

Comment: Didn't work off the bat but after a bit of tweaking I managed to get it working

    /^([A-G#b]+)?([A-Z0-9+]*)$/i

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `a-z` and `#` to the body of the character set, converting your statement into:

```
preg_match('/A-G([A-Za-z0-9+#]?)/i', $start_key, $matches)
```